# JMeter reaching EOF too early in CSV file

Tags: csv, jmeter

I have setup an SMTP sampler in JMeter that gets the body data from a csv file. It reads the first element and then stops. Any suggestions on what could be wrong?

The CSV file looks like this:

```
"This is 
a multiline 
record
"`"This is
a seond
multi line
record
"`"And this is a third record"
```

Result

[image]

Configuration

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [CSV Data Set Config documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config)

> JMeter supports CSV files with quoted data that includes new-lines.

> By default, the file is only opened once, and each thread will use a different line from the file.

So the "line" with newline characters needs to start from the new line (hopefully it makes sense), you need to organize your CSV file a little bit differently to wit:

```
"This is 
a multiline 
record
"`
"This is
a seond
multi line
record
"`
"And this is a third record"
```

If you don't have possibility to amend your CSV file you will have to go for other options of reading the data, i.e. using [JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy scripts](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) or storing the data into the database and [using JDBC Test Elements for retrieving it](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-automatically-pull-data-from-a-db-for-your-performance-test)

Comment: I also removed the delimiter ` as I did not need it.